# SPOT 2-5 convert DN to TOA using QGIS

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, spot5

I'm new to QGIS and I would like to convert SPOT(2-5) images from DN to TOA.
How do I go about doing this? I've an idea of how to do it for Landsat images however I'm not sure about SPOT.

Comment: do you want to transform it to TOA radiance or TOA reflectance??

Comment: TOA reflectance

Answer (score 4):

There is two ways you can do this:

1. Inside the toolbox:

- Grass: i.atcorr: performs atmospheric correction (i don´t know if it works with spot)
- Orfeo Toolbox: Optical calibration (works with spot 5)

2. Inside toolbox --> band math

- you can read the metadata, look for the coeficients for the following equations ( for example: `<SUN_ELEVATION>, <PHYSICAL_BIAS>, <PHYSICAL_GAIN>`)
- you can find d in [Chander et al. 2009](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjj8rHX0JT6AhV4gv0HHfe8DEsQFnoECCIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fntrs.nasa.gov%2Fapi%2Fcitations%2F20090027884%2Fdownloads%2F20090027884.pdf&usg=AOvVaw089LtHWf3nUm_UWSYEym0V)
- you can find ESUN in [SPOT ESUN](https://web.archive.org/web/20120704043211/http://www.astrium-geo.com/files/pmedia/public/r452_9_normalsolarirradiance.pdf)
- transform DN to TOA radiance (`L=DN/Ak`; A= bandgain, B=bandbias)
- transform TOA radiance to TOA reflectance (`p=[PI*d^2*L]/[ESUN*cos(theta)]`; PI=3,14..., d= distance to solar to earth, L = TOA radiance, ESUN = Mean exoatmospheric solar irradiance, theta = Solar zenith angle (90-SUN_ELEVATION))
- you must do this for every band

Comment: The equation works however for Spot it should be (p=[PI**L]/[ESUN*d^2*cos(theta)]

Comment: theta should be solar zenith angle in radians, right?

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking online a lot for information regarding this, but it's pretty sparse because most links and resources have gone dead since this question was asked.

The [SPOT World Heritage CARTO 2A FAQ](https://swh-2a-carto.fr/faq) outlines what you would need to do (AFTER downloading a zipped L1A SPOT file from the [SPOT World Heritage Portal](https://regards.cnes.fr/user/swh/modules/60), putting it into the CARTO processing service, and receiving a cartographically projected but radiometrically/atmospherically uncorrected 'N2A' file).

The FAQ includes the ESUN/Esλ values for all SPOT Satellites. As of this posting date, you can still make use of this service, but here's an [Archive Version](https://web.archive.org/web/20220913141212/https://swh-2a-carto.fr/faq) of the FAQ; you can still apply these equations to an L1A-non-CARTO image as the <PHYSICAL_GAIN>/<SUN_ELEVATION> properties are buried within the METADATA.DIM files if you open them up in Notepad or a DIM-reading software.

It's simplified with slightly different correction steps using an L1A/'N2A-CARTO' file:

**1. DN to TOA Radiance: `Lλ= DN / G`**

*Lλ = TOA Radiance of the spectral band, in W/m²/sr/µm*

*DN = Dimensionless Number*

*G = Gain, referred to as <PHYSICAL GAIN> in the accompanying 'CARTO_2A'.xml/L1A METADATA.DIM file, for EACH band*

**2. TOA Radiance to TOA Reflectance: `ρλ = (π * Lλ) / (cos(θsz) * (Esλ * dsun(t))`**

*ρλ = TOA Reflectance*

*π = pi, aka 3.14*

*Lλ = TOA Radiance, your answer from 1.*

*cos(θsz) = Cosine of Solar Zenith Angle, <SUN_ELEVATION> in the 'CARTO_2A'.xml/L1A METADATA.DIM file*

*Esλ = Mean Average Solar Irradiance for a Band. It has to be corrected against dsun(t) for that day of image acquisition, see 2a.*

**2a. `dsun(t) = 1 / (1 - e * cos[n{t-to}])^2`**

*e = orbit eccentricity (0.01673)*

*n = mean rotation angle (0.0172 rad / day)*

*t =  Julian day of image acquisition date, i.e. January 10th is 10; March 3rd would be 62*

*to = 2. SWH doesn't say what this is*

Plug these equations into QGIS/ your GIS/EO software of choice with Band Maths for each band individually, and you're away.